# Перемещение объектов по Интервалу

Tags: javascript, jquery

Надо что-бы каждый новый круг перемещался по другому сторону, у меня каждый новый круг и прошедшие идут по ту же сторону, и в итоге оказываются в одном месте, (перемещение идет по рандомному числу) , выполните мой код и поймете о чем говорю)))

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let c;
  let qanak = 0;
  let x = 0;
  let y = 0;
  $("#chaos").click(function() {
    clearInterval(c)
    c = setInterval(function() {
      qanak++
      if (qanak == 50) {
        clearInterval(c)
      }
      let tp = parseInt(Math.random() * 700)
      let lft = parseInt(Math.random() * 1000)
      var circle = $("<div></div")
      circle.css({
        width: "100px",
        height: "100px",
        background: "gold",
        position: "absolute",
        "border-radius": "50%",
        top: tp + "px",
        left: lft + "px",
      });
      let x = parseInt(Math.random() * 700)
      let y = parseInt(Math.random() * 1000)
      $("div").css({
        top: x + "px",
        left: y + "px",
      })
      circle.appendTo("body")
    }, 1000)
  })
});
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

div {
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn btn-danger" id="chaos">Starting Chaos</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы делаете для всех `div` одинаковые `top` и `left`. Вместо этого я предлагаю сделать `top` и `left` разным для каждого `div`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let c;
  let qanak = 0;
  let x = 0;
  let y = 0;
  $("#chaos").click(function() {
    clearInterval(c)
    c = setInterval(function() {
      qanak++
      if (qanak == 50) {
        clearInterval(c)
      }
      let tp = parseInt(Math.random() * 700)
      let lft = parseInt(Math.random() * 1000)
      var circle = $("<div></div")
      circle.css({
        width: "100px",
        height: "100px",
        background: "gold",
        position: "absolute",
        "border-radius": "50%",
        top: tp + "px",
        left: lft + "px",
      });
      $("div").each(function() {
        let x = parseInt(Math.random() * 700);
        let y = parseInt(Math.random() * 1000);
        $(this).css({
          top: x + "px",
          left: y + "px",
        });
      })
      circle.appendTo("body")
    }, 1000)
  })
});
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

div {
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn btn-danger" id="chaos">Starting Chaos</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое